# how to check if certain consumer is connected to Kafka 0.9.0.x using java?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

**How to get list of connected consumers on kafka?** As consumers are connected on broker, is there any java utility like ZkClient/ZkUtils to get list of connected consumers in Kafka 0.9.0.x? Like we use to get list of brokers using below utility:

```
        ZkClient zkClient = new ZkClient(endpoint.getZookeeperConnect(), 60000);

        if(zkClient!=null){
            List<String> brokerIds = zkClient.getChildren(ZkUtils.BrokerIdsPath());
            if(CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(brokerIds) &&  brokerIds.contains(brokerId)){
                logger.debug("Broker:{{}} is connected to Zookeeper.",brokerId);
                flag = true;    
            }
            else{
                logger.error("ERROR:Broker:{{}} is not connected to Zookeeper.",brokerId);
            }
            zkClient.close();
        }
```

I am using Kafka 0.9.0.x with below java lib from maven :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

**UPDATED:**

i opened a '**kafka-console-consumer.bat**' and ran it once then crossed the cmd prompt. Then went on to "**zookeeper-shell.bat**" and ***ls /consumers*** it then showed [console-consumer-6008], but my programmed consumers are not shown. using `zkClient.getChildren(ZkUtils.ConsumersPath())` i can now view only mentioned consumer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure exactly what information do you need, but I did a sample program that gives the same information than kafka-consumer-groups.sh --describe.

To use this code add this dependencies to your pom.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Then:

```
import org.apache.kafka.clients.CommonClientConfigs;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer;
import org.apache.kafka.common.TopicPartition;
import kafka.admin.AdminClient;
import kafka.coordinator.GroupOverview;

Properties props = new Properties();
props.put(CommonClientConfigs.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "kafka-1:9092");
AdminClient adminClient = AdminClient.create(props);

List<GroupOverview> groups =  scala.collection.JavaConversions.seqAsJavaList(
        adminClient.listAllConsumerGroupsFlattened());
for (GroupOverview group : groups) {
    String groupId = group.groupId();

    Properties consProps = new Properties();
    consProps.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "kafka-1:9092");
    consProps.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupId);
    consProps.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, "false");
    consProps.put(ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, "30000");
    consProps.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
    consProps.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
    KafkaConsumer consumer = new KafkaConsumer(consProps);

    List<AdminClient.ConsumerSummary> groupSummaries = scala.collection.JavaConversions.seqAsJavaList(
            adminClient.describeConsumerGroup(groupId));

    System.out.println("GROUP, TOPIC, PARTITION, CURRENT OFFSET, LOG END OFFSET, LAG, OWNER");

    for (AdminClient.ConsumerSummary summary : groupSummaries) {
        String owner = summary.clientId() + "_" + summary.clientHost();
        List<TopicPartition> topicPartitions = scala.collection.JavaConversions.seqAsJavaList(
                summary.assignment());
        for (TopicPartition tp : topicPartitions) {

            // Get current offset
            long currentOffset = consumer.committed(tp).offset();

            // get log end offset
            consumer.assign(Arrays.asList(tp));
            consumer.seekToEnd();
            long logEndOffset = consumer.position(tp);

            long lag = logEndOffset - currentOffset;

            System.out.println(groupId + ", " + tp.topic() + ", " + tp.partition() + ", " +
                    currentOffset + ", " + logEndOffset + ", " + lag + ", " + owner);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what i needed to get list of Running Consumers only. this was achieved using "AdminClient" + "listAllConsumerGroupsFlattened()" method. Things are quite hidden in kafak yet.

Answer (score 1):

For 0.9.x new consumer and list all active consumer groups:

1. find all brokers and send "ListGroups" request to each of broker and get all group information;

For details you can refer to `$KAFKA_HOME/bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh`(**kafka.admin.ConsumerGroupCommand.KafkaConsumerGroupService.list()**)

For 0.9.x new consumer and describe certain consumer group detailed information:

1. find consumer group coordinator and send "DescribeGroups" request to it and get all group members information and partition assignment information;
2. call KafkaConsumer.committed(TopicPartition partition) to get the last committed offset for the given partition.

For details you can refer to `$KAFKA_HOME/bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh`(**kafka.admin.ConsumerGroupCommand.KafkaConsumerGroupService.describe()**)

Please be noted that old consumer and new consumer have complete different implementation about that.(Both logic are implemented in **kafka.admin.ConsumerGroupCommand**.

Comment: this edit was a mistake had to add in my own question, sorry for it dont know how to discard it.

Comment: BTW i am using java code on windows, Kafka Windows do not have 'kafka-consumer-groups.bat' what to do now.

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty much the same but you have to check ZkUtils.ConsumersPath (= /consumers).

The consumers structure in Zookeeper is the next /consumers/[groupId]/ids/[consumerId] so navigating you can get the the groups and consumer for each group.

Comment: ZkUtils.ConsumersPath (/consumers) always returned [ ]. I think consumer groups info is now saved on kafka. I have already gone through  this part to verify consumers list.

Comment: In 0.9.x and 0.10.x still persist consumers groups and consumer. You can check it in the code ZkUtils.getConsumers get the ConsumersPath's children. https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/core/src/main/scala/kafka/utils/ZkUtils.scala#L864

Comment: zkClient.getChildren(ZkUtils.ConsumersPath()) returns empty [ ].

Comment: Try with the shell, open a console producer and console consumer. Then produce a message. Finally check with the tool zookeeper shell ls /consumers = [console-consumer-44669] If it works, everything is ok and the error will be on your consumers that are not registered. I've just tried and I saw the consumer in zk /consumers node.

Comment: i opened a 'kafka-console-consumer.bat' and ran it once then crossed the cmd prompt. Then went on to "zookeeper-shell.bat" and ls /consumers it then showed [console-consumer-6008], but my programmed consumers are not shown. using 'zkClient.getChildren(ZkUtils.ConsumersPath())' i can now view only mentioned consumer.